# From Position/Target to Orientation/Elevation

Tags: sharpdx

I have an orbit camera class that calculates the camera position from Orientation/Elevation and distance from target. I decided to replace these initial values for the camera instantiation with simply Vector3's position and target. How do I calculate Orientation/Elevation and distance from target from these two vectors?

I only got as far as creating a Matrix (Matrix.LookAt) and decomposing it. The translation that can be used for the distance from target partition is trivial, but what do I do with the Quaternion portion to get the elevation/orientation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Z is the vertical axis, the orientation in the XY plane can be computed using `atan2`:

```
float dx = target.x - position.x;
float dy = target.y - position.y;

yaw = atan2(dy, dx);
```

And same for the elevation angle:

```
float dz = target.z - position.z;

pitch = atan2(dz, sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
```

Comment: I can't get the correct result with this, but this might be due to my misunderstanding of what goes where. I'm using SharpDX where the backward RH direction of the Z-axis is Vector3(0,0,1). The vertical axis that you mentioned is Y and up is Vector3(0,1,0).

Comment: I tried to swap the dy and dz values to match the XZ plane to no avail.

Comment: Well, swapping `dy` and `dz` is the way to go. Maybe you’re not converting radians back to degrees?

Comment: I did convert to degrees.

Is my reordered calculation correct?


`float dx = target.x - position.x;
float dz = target.z - position.z;

yaw = atan2(dz, dx); //orientation in radians

float dy = target.y - position.y;

pitch = atan2(dz, sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz)); // elevation in radians`

Comment: Ah. If you switch Y and Z, the first argument to the second `atan2` call should become `dy`.

Comment: I got fairly close with 

`float dx = position.X - target.X;
float dz = position.Z - target.Z;
orientation = -(float)Math.Atan2(dx, dz); //orientation in radians
float dy = position.Y - target.Y;
elevation = (float)Math.Atan2(dy, Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz)); // elevation in radians
distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(target, position);`

Notice that I had to flip the position and target in subtraction and add the negative in the first atan2 calc. The problem now is precision. I tried a bunch of test cases where the components should be exactly 0.0 and I end up with values like -2.6E06

Comment: I tried to reduce this by getting rid of degrees altogether to no avail.

Comment: I suppose you mean `2.6e-06`. That is perfectly normal when doing computations with floating point numbers. You can get slightly better precision using `double` instead of `float`, but I see little reason to aim for that: a difference of `2.6e-06` in the camera orientation is a displacement smaller than a thousandth of a pixel.

Comment: I suppose so. This is the first time I see floating point error in any of the camera or position calculations, but considering it doesn't matter when it comes to translating this into a pixel I suppose it's not important.